# Spring boot 2 application context xml hibernate properties

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I am converting an old Spring app to Spring boot. So I will be still using the existing xml configuration instead of annotations. In the appContext.xml, I have configured the hibernate properties to be read from the application properties as follows.

```
<bean id="appSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${spring.jpa.database-platform}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${spring.jpa.show-sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${spring.jpa.format-sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>               
        </props>
    </property>
```

Otherwise those hibernate properties will not be set just by only using the application.properties. But the datasource is automatically created by reading the application.properties file. Can anyone tell me what I am missing for hibernate properties? I definitely want to keep the appContext.xml as changing it to use annotation only requires lot of refactoring.

This is my application.properties.

```
spring.datasource.type=org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
spring.datasource.url=xxxxxx
spring.datasource.username=xxxx
spring.datasource.password=xxxxx
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=15
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=20000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=50
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=15
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=8
spring.datasource.tomcat.default-auto-commit=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.format-sql=false
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be set only by application.properties.

```xml
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${spring.jpa.database-platform}</prop>
            ...            
        </props>
    </property>
```

to

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=${spring.jpa.database-platform}
...
```

good luck

Comment: what about "hibernate.show_sql" ? Am I setting it wrongly in the application.properties?

Comment: No. You did not go wrong. One works in the Jpa layer and one in the Hibernate layer. Jpa is wrapping Hibernate.

Comment: hibernate.show_sql in application.properties didn't work in my scenario. That is why I asked this question

Comment: `hibernate.show_sql` -> `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql`